# Android Studio - The 'activity' element must be a direct child of the 'application' element

Tags: android, manifest

I have coded a language function for my program which requires a module to be declared in the manifest and I have done it as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="cz.nakoncisveta.eyetracksample.eyedetect"
android:versionCode="301"
android:versionName="3.01">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name="com.example.donteh.cvimagedetection.LanguageOverride"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.donteh.cvimagedetection.UiActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/eyes">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.donteh.cvimagedetection.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges = "keyboardHidden|orientation" />
</application>
```

The compiler is giving me an error at the application tag saying "The 'activity' element must be a direct child of the 'application' element. I've googled it and the common problem seems to be some 'activity' elements being out of the 'application' element. However, I've made sure that all 'activity' elements are under the 'application' element.

Strangely, adding a closing bracket to the application tag seems to solve the problem. However, this means that I can't declare the module which would be a problem.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="cz.nakoncisveta.eyetracksample.eyedetect"
android:versionCode="301"
android:versionName="3.01">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application>
    android:name="com.example.donteh.cvimagedetection.LanguageOverride"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.donteh.cvimagedetection.UiActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/eyes">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.donteh.cvimagedetection.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges = "keyboardHidden|orientation" />
</application>
```

Comment: The opening `<application>` tag is self-closed. That is, in the first manifest, remove the `/` at the end of that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this line:

```
<application
android:name="com.example.donteh.cvimagedetection.LanguageOverride"/>
```

The `/>` at the end of the tag means that it is self-closing. You don't want to do this in this case as you want to enclose child elements such as `<activity>`. To fix this error, remove the `/` at the end of the tag like so:

```
<application
android:name="com.example.donteh.cvimagedetection.LanguageOverride">
```